# Importing CSV file PostgreSQL using pgAdmin 4

Tags: postgresql, csv, import, pgadmin-4, csv-import

I'm trying to import a CSV file to my PostgreSQL but I get this error

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "id;date;time;latitude;longitude"
CONTEXT:  COPY test, line 1, column id: "id;date;time;latitude;longitude"
```

my csv file is simple

```
id;date;time;latitude;longitude
12980;2015-10-22;14:13:44.1430000;59,86411203;17,64274849
```

The table is created with the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE kordinater.test
(
    id integer NOT NULL,
    date date,
    "time" time without time zone,
    latitude real,
    longitude real
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE kordinater.test
    OWNER to postgres;
```

Comment: Hi, can you help me with this related post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60087614/unable-to-upload-csv-file-to-a-postgresql-database

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Import/Export` option for this task.

1. Right click on your table
2. Select "Import/Export" option & Click
3. Provide proper option
4. Click Ok button

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should try this it must work

COPY kordinater.test(id,date,time,latitude,longitude) 
FROM 'C:\tmp\yourfile.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;

Your csv header must be separated by **comma** NOT WITH semi-colon or try to change id column type to bigint

[to know more](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/import-csv-file-into-posgresql-table/)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the quickest way to overcome this issue is to create an intermediary temporary table, so that you can import your data and cast the coordinates as you please.

Create a similar **[temporary table](http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/statements/create_temporary_table)** with the problematic columns as `text`:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp
(
    id integer,
    date date,
    time time without time zone,
    latitude text,
    longitude text
);
```

And import your file using `COPY`:

```
COPY tmp FROM '/path/to/file.csv' DELIMITER ';' CSV HEADER;
```

Once you have your data in the `tmp` table, you can cast the coordinates and insert them into the `test` table with this command:

```
INSERT INTO test (id, date, time, latitude, longitude) 
SELECT id, date, time, replace(latitude,',','.')::numeric, replace(longitude,',','.')::numeric from tmp;
```

One more thing:

Since you're working with geographic coordinates, I sincerely recommend you to take a look at [**PostGIS**](https://postgis.net/). It is quite easy to install and makes your life much easier when you start your first calculations with geospatial data.